# Hiding custom status bar view after implementation in AppDelegate

Tags: objective-c, ios7, statusbar

I created my status bar with following code in appDelegate class.

```
   UIView *statusBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 20)];
        theView.backgroundColor = customGrayColor;
        [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:statusBarView];
```

Now I want to hide it in one of the viewCOntrollers dynamically. I'm hiding both Navigation bar and the status bar.

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

I can see the status bar has been hidden, as all the text does hide,  but just the gray colored view doesn't hide.

And scope of problem is only iOS 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];` you hide native application status bar that is instance of `UIStatusBar` class. But it doesn't hide your custom view `statusBarView` that is instance of `UIView` class.
For hiding  custom view call:
`statusBarView.hidden = YES;`
or
`[statusBarView removeFromSuperView]`.

If you need hide it from `ViewController` then consider adding property to `AppDelegate` for storing  `statusBarView` and accessing it from any other place.

Comment: Good idea. Let me give it a quick try.

Comment: If I created a property AppDelegate, and created an Appdelegate Object in my VC like this: `AppDelegate *delegateObj = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];`. I cannot access the custom property. Can you clarify how I need to create the property in app delegate class ?

Comment: @CalZone, you need set property in AppDelegate.h file like: `@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) UIView *statusBarView;` for accessing it use: `delegateObj.statusBarView`.

Comment: Got it done. My problem was I was using `@class Appdelegate;` instead of `#import Appdelegate`. Thank you. I'll mark it as answer.